# how to check if ssh command ran through pexpect spawn command ran successfully or not .

Tags: python, expect

I am writing a simple python script to test connectivity to multiple linux hosts running centos on them. For this I am thinking of using pexpect module and ssh . pexpect will send the password stored in a variable when prompted for. The problem is that how to check if the password was accepted successfully or not. Is there a way to do so. The code is given below. Please add you expert comments.

This example has code written to ssh to localhost only.So a for loop is not yet included.

```
import pexpect
from getpass import getpass
import sys

# Defining Global Variables

log_file = '/tmp/AccessValidation'

# Getting password from user and storing in a variable 

passs = getpass("Please enter your password: ")

# Connect to server using ssh connection and run a command to verify access.

child = pexpect.spawn("ssh -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 127.0.0.1 'uptime'")
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(passs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things you could do is to have an `expect` for the command prompt. So if your prompt is: `someuser@host$` you could do `child.expect(".*\$")`.

Another thing you could do is to have multiple expects and then check those against the ones you want. For example:

```
i = child.expect([".*\$", "Password Incorrect"])
if i != 0:
    print "Incorrect credentials"
else:
    print "Command executed correctly"
```

You can view some [examples](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) within [Pexpect's readthedocs page.](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/) Pexpect also has the [pxssh](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pxssh.html) class that is specialized to handle ssh connections and may be of some use also. I personally haven't used it but the syntax seems the same, just with more options relating to ssh.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Cory Shay for helping me  figure out the correct way to solve my problem . Below is the code I have written and this works.

```
import pexpect
from getpass import getpass
import sys

# Defining Global Variables

log_file = '/tmp/AccessValidation'

# Getting password from user and storing in a variable 

passs = getpass("Please enter your password: ")

# Connect to server using ssh connection and run a command to verify access.

child = pexpect.spawn("ssh -q -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 127.0.0.1 'hostname' ")
child.expect('Password:')
child.sendline(passs)

result = child.expect(['Password:', pexpect.EOF])
if result == 0:
    print "Access Denied"
elif result == 1:
    print "Access Granted"
```